# How to format DateTime / TimeSpan from String in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, timespan

I receive a string in this format "7:00 am - 11:00 pm" representing start and end time. **The string will always have two times.** Now I need to format that to today's date & time so in above case it's easy. It comes to 18th March 7 AM - 18th March 11 PM but there is an edge case where time is like "7:00 am - 12:00 am", in this case it will need to be converted to 18th March 7 AM - 19th March 12 AM.

Now I can handle this using if :D. So whenever the second token is smaller than first token (e.g. "7:00 am - 02:00 am") I can increase the date of the second part.

```
string input = "7:00 am - 12:00 am";
List<DateTime> tokens = input.Split('-').Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Trim(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-NZ"))).ToList();
if(tokens[1] < tokens[0]){
    tokens[1] = tokens[1].AddDays(1);   
}
```

[image]

But I would like to know if there is any builtin way in C# itself through Timespan, Datetime classes etc to handle it.

Comment: Will you always have pairs of times, or could the input be just "7:00 am"?

Comment: Yes always pair of times - so two of them - start and finish.

Comment: There isn't any built-in method to check for overlapping days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is okay for the requirements you have listed, you could consider hiding some of the logic away by creating an extension method and using [`DateTime.Hour`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=netframework-4.7.2) in your if statement:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> ToDateTimePairs(this string input)
    {
        var dates = input.Split('-').Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Trim(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-NZ"))).ToList();           

        if (dates[1].Hour < dates[0].Hour)
        {
            dates[1] = dates[1].AddDays(1);
        }

        return dates;
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
string input = "7:00 am - 12:00 am";
var dates = input.ToDateTimePairs();
foreach(var date in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Aside: You could also add some validation steps in `ToDateTimePairs()` (you should only have two valid `DateTime` objects after splitting the string, etc). The way you implement it is up to you; right now, if an invalid date is contained in the string, the call to `DateTime.Parse()` will throw a `FormatException` - if you'd like to handle the validation of the parsing yourself, consider using [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.